# Handling boolean values and empty strings for a property in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON property that can be one of

```
{ "observed": true }
{ "observed": false }
{ "observed": "" }
```

I'd like to map it so that in Java it will one of `"true"`, `"false"` or `""`

```
@JsonProperty("observed")
private String observedValue;
```

Then I'll just make a getter that would give me a

```
public Optional<Boolean> getObservedOpt() {
    if ("".equals(observedValue)) {
       return Optional.empty();
    } else {
       return Optional.of(Boolean.parseBoolean(observedValue));
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure how to make it converted `true` and `false` into strings.  Or perhaps there's a more elegant way of doing it without the string comparison.

Comment: Can you try with variable type set to Object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest configure object mapper with this feature [ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT), so in case of empty string it will be assigned to `null`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
```

And you can happily declare this field as `Boolean` type, be aware in case of empty string this field value will be `null`

```
@JsonProperty("observed")
private Boolean observedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be using Custom JsonDeserializer

```
public static class StringBooleanDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
            if(parser.getValueAsBoolean()){
                return "true";
            }else{
                if(parser.getTextLength()==0) {
                    return parser.getText();
                }else{
                    return "false";
                }

            }
        }
    }

@JsonProperty("observed")
@JsonDeserialize(using=StringBooleanDeserializer.class)
private String observedValue;
```

Similarly, you can also write custom JSON Serializer.